# Как организовать такое меню?

Tags: menu, android, java

Я вот часто вижу: вызываешь меню - появляется страница с опциями, выбираешь нужные, ставишь галочки где надо, нажимаешь клавишу "назад" - появляется предыдущая страница, работаешь дальше. Как это сделать? Напишите пож. или дайте толковую ссылку, можно по-английски или по-немецки.

Answer (score 2):

[PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems(java.lang.CharSequence[], boolean[], android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)), если интересуют именно галочки, но можно и выбор радиокнопками, простым списком и др. )